# The use of the present simple in context

Tags: present-simple

Tell me please why the present simple was used instead of the past simple in the following context.

> Have you ever talked with a friend about a problem, only to realize that  **he just doesn't grasp** why the issue is so important to you? Have you ever presented an idea to a group of people and **it's met** with utter confusion?

It is from this [video](http://Have%20you%20ever%20talked%20with%20a%20friend%20about%20a%20problem,%20only%20to%20realize%20that%20%20he%20just%20doesn't%20grasp%20why%20the%20issue%20is%20so%20important%20to%20you?%20Have%20you%20ever%20presented%20an%20idea%20to%20a%20group%20of%20people%20and%20it's%20met%20with%20utter%20confusion?). It is right at the begining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a writing style thing.

The present simple is used in hypothetical situations to create a sense of immediacy, like you're right in the moment with the speaker. It's more engaging with simple present because you imagine the situation as if it's happening now, rather than simply asking yourself whether that has ever happened to you in the past.

Answer (score 0):

in the first sentence it uses present because (i assume) the friend Still doesn't grasp the problem while in the second one it uses past because (again, I assume) the idea is **no longer** met with utter confusion